# Add multiple SHA for same OAuth for Google SignIn Android

Tags: android, google-signin

I have followed [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) document to implement google signIn in android. It is working fine. There are two developers working on the same project, so I have to add 2 SHA for two different systems from which the build will be generated. But the credentials console does not showing any add button to add another SHA for the same project.

How can I add SHA for other system or is there any way to use same OAuth for different SHA but same package name.

[image: Google API console]

Comment: Please give reason for down vote

Comment: This might be twisting the question itself but, have you looked into Firebase Authentication? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ Afaik, it supports setting up several SHA1 keys to the project hence allowing you to use debug as well as release key and any more keys you generate for the project.

Comment: Yes I know about Firebase authentication, but I am not using it. I want to do it with Google Sign In only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a [link](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/03/registering-oauth-clients-for-google.html) which describes- **Handling multiple environments - Registering other client IDs for your project**. So the solution is to create different client Id for release environments.
So, I will award the bounty to @keepTrackOfYourStack for a close answer.

[image]

Comment: Wow that's a great post

Answer (score 0):

You can add a shared key to project repository that is shared by all developers and is used to sign debug build type. This way you only need to add SHA of this shared key to the google console.

Comment: I want to use the same client id(as shown in image) for all systems and build variant(i.e, debug and release). The client Id is already shared between developers.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong but is n't that why you can add another client to the app.  The other developer would just use the other client...I tested and was able to create more than one.

Comment: I think its not a best practice for an application have different client Ids.

Answer (score 0):

The *SHA1* is **specific to an individual system** just like MAC Address, for different systems to have same key for a specific project you need to modify your *build* file.

You need to copy the debug key from one of your team mate and provide it to all of the team members.

The location of your debug keystore will be here normally;

```
C:\Users\your_user_name\.android\debug.keystore
```

and copy it to the same location of other team mates.
Modify your **gradle** file so that it will pick the shared debug keystore.

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
    debug {
        storeFile file("debug.keystore")
    }
```